# How do I solve a system of equations for only one variable quickly?

Tags: equation-solving

I have four order-2 polynomial equations in four unknowns. Call the unknowns `x1`,`x2`,`x3`,`x4`. I want only `x1`, and am not at all interested in the values of `x2`,`x3`,`x4`.

Obviously `Solve[{…,…,…,…}, {x1,x2,x3,x4}]` should give the answer and more. But takes a long time of CPU whirring: indeed, it hasn’t finished. Is there a way to tell `Solve` (or another function) that `x2`,`x3`,`x4` are not to appear in the solution for `x1`, but that there is no need to solve for them? If so, please, how?

Indeed, I would much rather that `Solve` return the coefficients of the polynomial for `x1`, rather than returning the solution to that (perhaps high-order) polynomial. Can `Solve` also be instructed to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Does using `Eliminate` help speed up the computation?  I have the following in mind: `Solve[Eliminate[{…,…,…,…}, {x2,x3,x4}],x1]`.  Perhaps you could give us a working example?

Comment: Can you try `GroebnerBasis[{equations}, x1, {x2, x3, x4}]`?

Comment: Both answers excellent, the GroebnerBasis being slightly superior as it returns the polynomial rather than requiring solution of a remaining equation. Both shorten the run-time to instantaneous.

Comment: Then, can you answer your own question?

Comment: Well, now I can (thank you), but surely you (J.M.) deserve the points/credit/whatever.

Comment: @J.M.  @JM  @J  @QuantumDot   Thank you for this help. These two are hugely faster and more efficient than `Solve` and discard. But even `GroebnerBasis` sometimes grinds to a halt.
http://www.jdawiseman.com/2015/20151128_GroebnerBasis_slow.nb
contains a complete description of the problem, and a too-slow `GroebnerBasis`. Please, any advice would be welcomed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As J.M. posted in a comment, `GroebnerBasis[{equations}, x1, {x2, x3, x4}]` does exactly what was asked.

But a commendation also goes to QuantumDot’s suggestion of `Solve[Eliminate[{…,…,…,…}, {x2,x3,x4}],x1]`.

Both reduced the run-time to seemingly instantaneous.

Comment: You might get a speed boost with `GroebnerBasis[{equations}, x1, {x2, x3, x4}, MonomialOrder->EliminationOrder]`.